# Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apt

I got below error while run `sudo apt-get update`, I found similar questions but does not help me. What actually I need to fix that issues.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm not seeing anything like `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release` in `/etc/apt/source.list` actually where it is came from.

can anyone suggest neat way to solve this error

Comment: Have you checked the /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory as well?